# Where are the cities of the of the gods?

Tags: gods, lokas, matsya-purana

[Chapter 124](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/23350/25F_Chapter_124_1.pdf#page=2&zoom=auto,-37,347) from Matsya Purana describes the cities of Indra, Varuna, Yama and Chandra surrounding Mount Meru and the Lokaloka mountains where the four guardians of the directions stay.

> In other words, the Earth has the same measurement as the Heaven. To
> the east of Meru, on the Manasottara mountain, is Vastveka-Sara, the
> city of Mahendra. It is full of gold.
>
> To the south of Meru is the city of Dharmaraja, called the Samyamana,
> on the back of the Manasa mountain. Vaivasvata Dharmaraja resides
> there.
>
> To the west of Sumeru, on the top of the Manasa mountain, is the fair
> city of Varuna named Susa.
>
> North of the Meru, on the top of the Manasa mountain, is the Vibhavari
> city of Moon (Sirnea). It is like the city of Mahendra.
>
> To the north of the Manasa mountain, are the Lokapalas in the four
> directions, for the propagation of virtue and the protection of the
> universe.

[The description](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vairaja%20abode%20of%20brahma&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1600&bih=767) of this book 'Religion and Philosophy of the Padma Purana' also describes Brahma's abode as Vairaja and ascribes it to the Padma Purana.

Are there such cities of other gods as well?

And what is the difference between the cities of the gods and the Lokas associated with them? (Like Indraloka, Somaloka, Vishnuloka etc.)